# PDF Writing programatically using Java itext

Tags: itext

**Task:** I am trying to Edit a PDF Form programmatic manner using java.

**Issue:** Currently i am using i text libraries where i am unable to get position(x and y coordinates) of a text where i want to write in the PDF.

**What i have already tried:** implemented RenderListner but TextRenderInfo.getText() gives me the half a word or a chars.

**What i want:** i want to get rendered text in a proper word formatted as it is in pdf document.

I need example of PDF text editing using itext java.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: *"i want to get rendered text in a proper word formatted as it is in pdf document."* - If *TextRenderInfo.getText() gives you the half a word or a chars*, then **that is *"as it is in pdf document"***. Usually between those half words or individual chars there is a very small left or right shift of the text insertion point (called *kerning*) to make the output more pleasing to the eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is not easy to do (I am hesitant to even say impossible).
According to the spec, pdf documents need only contain the instructions needed to render the document in a viewer.
One of the symptoms of that (which you are seeing with TextRenderInfo) is that there is no real concept of structure.

For instance the paragraph "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet" might get rendered as:
render "Ipsum Do"
render "Lorem " (space included)
render "lor"
render "Sit Amet" (leading space not included, but realized by shifting position)

TextRenderInfo is doing exactly what the name suggests, you are getting information about each text rendering instruction. The standard itself makes it impossible to give guarantees like "it will always contain a full word/phrase" or "instructions appear in logical reading order".

If you are doing this to get the location of some piece of text, simply collect all TextRenderInfo objects, and sort with a custom comparator that takes their position into account. Once sorted, you can loop over them, by doing so you have information about the text being rendered and the coordinates at which the text is being rendered. Look in SimpleTextExtractionStrategy to get an idea of how we do this.

If you want to inject custom values into a pdf (you mentioned editing), the consider using forms (XFA or acro). Forms allow you to basically define placeholders that iText can later fill with content. Some form elements will allow dynamic resizing.

If you have access to the data before it gets turned into a pdf, it would be of course even better to manipulate the data at that point. Since editing a pdf (programmatically) is by nature a hard problem to tackle.